# Why do I get an invalid column name error when using a temp table twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

If I run each of these batches separately, it works. However, if they are combined into one script (like what is done when a DACPAC script runs, or putting them both into one tab in SSMS), I get an `Invalid column name` error on the second insert. Why is that? If I need these to run in one script, do I need to use a different name for the temp table for the second batch? Or am I missing something that would allow me to use the same name?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#source') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #source
SELECT FirstName, LastName INTO #source FROM Musician WHERE 1 = 0; -- set up temp table schema
INSERT INTO #source ( FirstName, LastName )
VALUES
('Geddy', 'Lee'),
('Alex', 'Lifeson') 

SELECT * FROM #source

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#source') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #source
SELECT [Name], Genre INTO #source FROM Band WHERE 1 = 0; -- set up temp table schema
INSERT INTO #source ( [Name], Genre )
VALUES
('Rush', 'Rock'),
('Ratt', 'Rock') 

SELECT * FROM #source

GO
```

Comment: The semicolons vs GO are the issue. If you use 2 GO's instead of the semicolons, it works fine. Not sure exactly why regarding the internals.

Comment: Side note, with SQL Server 2016 + you can use slightly cleaner syntax - `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #source`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each batch is parsed independently. So it works when you use `GO` because they are in different batches.

When you put everything in the same batch, SQL Server parses what it sees, and it is blind to logic like `DROP` commands hidden behind `IF` conditionals. Try the following and you'll find the same:

```sql
IF (1=0) DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #x; CREATE TABLE #x(i int);
IF (1=1) DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #x; CREATE TABLE #x(j date);
```

You and I both know that only one of those will ever *execute*, but the parser spots the redundant table name before it ever gets to execution (or evaluating any conditionals).

This works because, again, each batch is now parsed in isolation:

```sql
IF (1=0) DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #x; CREATE TABLE #x(i int);
GO
IF (1=1) DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #x; CREATE TABLE #x(j date);
```

This will in fact *fail* even though it passes parsing (highlight and select `Parse` instead of `Execute`), so the blindness goes both ways:

```sql
IF (1=0) DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #x; CREATE TABLE #x(i int);
GO
IF (1=1) CREATE TABLE #x(j date);
```

Comment: One reason why SQL's idea of mixing declarations and code is bad. A `create table #temp` should just be a `declare`, and should be compile-time verifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Using go after dropping the tables in both block will do the trick.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#source') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #source
go
SELECT FirstName, LastName INTO #source FROM Musician WHERE 1 = 0; -- set up temp table schema
INSERT INTO #source ( FirstName, LastName )
VALUES
('Geddy', 'Lee'),
('Alex', 'Lifeson') 

SELECT * FROM #source

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#source') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #source
go
SELECT [Name], Genre INTO #source FROM Band WHERE 1 = 0; -- set up temp table schema
INSERT INTO #source ( [Name], Genre )
VALUES
('Rush', 'Rock'),
('Ratt', 'Rock') 

SELECT * FROM #source

GO
```